# Is there a name for when you read two or more digits together rather than as a single number?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I say 'one-one' when I mean 'eleven' or 'two-three-four' when I mean 'two hundred and thirty four,' is there an expression for reading in digits like this?

Comment: I've seen _digitwise/digit-wise_ used to mean 'digit by digit', 'one digit at a time', but this doesn't appear in most dictionaries.

Comment: "Digit by digit"  is another term that's occasionally used, even if not established. I doubt it's listed in (m)any standard references.

Comment: Note the different pronunciations and meanings of **_9/11_** and **_911_** in the United States. The first is always pronounced _nine-eleven_ and refers to the terrorist attack in New York, while the second is always pronounced _nine-one-one_ and refers to the emergency phone number for disasters (which was established before 2001).

Answer (score 1):

A list of digits read one by one is a **string**. From Wolfram MathWorld:

> **[string](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/String.html)**: A string of length n on an alphabet l of m characters is an
> arrangement of n not necessarily distinct symbols from l. There are
> m^n such distinct strings.
>
> For example, the strings of length n=3 on the alphabet {1,2} are
> {1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,1}, {1,2,2}, {2,1,1}, {2,1,2}, {2,2,1}, and
> {2,2,2}.

For example, when one of your financial accounts requires identity verification, it may send you a six-digit code via email or text, e.g., 418967, which you have to enter into your computer or phone to access your account. 418967, when read digit by digit, is a six-digit string on the alphabet {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} of 10 characters, i.e., {4,1,8,9,6,7}.

So, in reading digits one by one, one is reading them as a **string**.

Comment: Isn't that a technical computer science definition? Are there citations for use in everyday English?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that reading these digits, as integers up to 9 (in number base ten), is the straightforward, goes-without-saying, regular way to read a such numerals.  I would call it punctuating the digits with commas, etc, to give the long form of a numeral.  Any word such as punctuating, drawing out, delineating.

Here's a related thread, which I came across, a few months ago.  The idea is to also pronounce numerals the way "spelled out".

[Why don't years have commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85555/why-dont-years-have-commas)

Perhaps, there is error-checking value to both these, and the other, approaches to working with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think "chunking" would be such a word.

> The phenomenon of chunking as a memory mechanism is easily observed in the way individuals group numbers, and information, in day-to-day life. For example, when recalling a number such as 12101946, if numbers are grouped as 12, 10, and 1946, a mnemonic is created for this number as a month, day, and year. It would be stored as December 10, 1946, instead of a string of numbers. Similarly, another illustration of the limited capacity of working memory as suggested by George Miller can be seen from the following example: While recalling a mobile phone number such as 9849523450, we might break this into 98 495 234 50. Thus, instead of remembering 10 separate digits that are beyond the putative "seven plus-or-minus two" memory span, we are remembering four groups of numbers. An entire chunk can also be remembered simply by storing the beginnings of a chunk in the working memory, resulting in the long-term memory recovering the remainder of the chunk.

Source: [Chunking (psychology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_(psychology))